# NextJS 13 Fetch Request Memoization

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js, next.js13, memoization

I am working on a React project with NextJS 13 and I have problems with using `request memoization` for `fetch`. It always sends request to backend even in the same request.

I have a simple endpoint at `http://localhost:8088/test` which only logs something to check if request is received. And I have the following code in my `page.tsx`. When I reload the page I see 4 logs in my backend server; 2 from metadata 2 from Page. Even though it is exactly the same request, it is not deduplicated as explained in [NextJS documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#request-memoization)

What am I missing here, why `fetch('http://localhost:8088/test')` is actually executed four times. How can I use request memoization so I can use the same data in both `Page` and `generateMetadata` and this code executes the request only once?

```
import { Metadata } from 'next';

export const dynamic = 'force-static';
export const fetchCache = 'force-no-store';

async function getItem() {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8088/test');
  return res.json();
}

export async function generateMetadata(): Promise<Metadata> {
  getItem();
  getItem();
  return {
    metadataBase: new URL('localhost:3000'),
    title: 'test'
  };
}

export default async function Page() {
  getItem();
  getItem();
  return (
    <>
      <p>test</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: You set ```fetchCache``` to ```force-no-store```. Did you try to remove it? Did you test your application in production or only in the development environment? Maybe try a production build?

Comment: I tried but it did not help. The problem happens only in development mode. In production mode it works fine. But I believe this should not happen also in development mode but I could not find any solution for that

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I'm facing the same issue at the moment.

Comment: no, I could not solve it in development mode

Comment: Even with the upcoming 14, this remains incredibly frustrating and time-consuming. Setting up a local environment for testing is a major challenge for me. I worry that the way things work in production might differ, making it hard to ensure accurate testing. The only success I've had in the development environment was when I implemented a cache function around getItem/fetch from React. However, this solution is just as frustrating as the initial issue.

Answer (score 0):

your `getItem` function does not get memoized. Its the `fetch` function itself that gets memoized. Your 'fetchItem' function isn't automatically memoized. you can test it:

create an api route in next.js. let's say /api/test/route.js:

```
export async function GET() {
  console.log('i am called');
  return Response.json({ message: 'yes' });
}
```

now make a request to this route "http://localhost:3000/api/test" inside `getItem`. `getItem` will be called 4 times but since `fetch` request is memoized you will see only one `console.log('i am called')` on your terminal because there will be only one `fetch` request.

you commented out that it works in production. I tested the code in dev ("next": "14.0.1") and looks like `next.js` is not caching by default. so you have to add this option  `cache: "force-cache"`

```
async function getItem() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/test", {
    cache: "force-cache",
  });
  // res.json async. needs to be awaited
  const data = await res.json();
  return data;
}
```

above code works:

[image]

you see `console.log` in route handler runs only once. Now if you run the code again, your `fetch` request will not reach api endpoint again even after you restart the dev server. you have to clear out the cache from refresh button of the page

Comment: > "I have a simple endpoint at http://localhost:8088/test which only logs something to check if request is received"
The problem is `fetch` being executed multiple times. I checked logs in the endpoint I call not my react app logs. And this only happens when I run in development mode. In production mode `fetch` is memoized

Answer (score -1):

To do request memoization, you can save the results of successful requests and return them for future requests without hitting the end.

**The basic example code is given below.**

```
import { Metadata } from 'next';

let count = 0;
let cachedItem = null;

async function getItem() {
  if (cachedItem) {
    return cachedItem;
  }

  const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"); // changed the api this is dummy api.
  const data = await res.json();
  cachedItem = data;
  console.log("call count",count);
  return data;
}

export async function generateMetadata() : Promise<Metadata> {
  await getItem();
  await getItem();
  return {
    metadataBase: new URL("localhost:3000"),
    title: "test"
  };
}

export default async function Page() {
  await getItem();
  await getItem();
  return (
    <>
      <p>test</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @zernab but these are async calls. The code you suggest may lead to "race condition" and more than one request may pass `if (cachedItem)` check at the same time and trigger fetch call. Since the `await fetch` would take time, it is very likely in this code `getItem` is called almost at the same time from both `Page` and `generateMetadata` and request would still be executed twice. Moreover I don't want to implement my own caching system since this is a feature promoted by NextJS and React.

Comment: You can use the "isFetching" flag along with this technique to avoid race conditions. eg:
let isFetching = false;
let cachedItem = null;

async function getItem() {
  if (cachedItem && !isFetching) {
    return cachedItem;
  }

    isFetching = true;
    try {
      const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
      cachedItem = res.json();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Some Error Message");
    } finally {
      isFetching = false;
    }

  return cachedItem;
}

Answer (score -2):

You should disable the cache in the `fetch` method. Remember please, in NextJs everything is based on conversions, not configs:

```js
const res = await fetch(
  'http://localhost:8088/test',
  { cache: 'no-store' }
);
```

By using this conversion, NextJs will understand not to cache anything in this component.

Comment: this also doen't help. cache: 'no-store' option is related with NextJS data cache. It is not related with `request memoization`. I think NextJS doesn't support this on development mode at all for some reason I cannot understand